# How can I fix weight issue in neural network

Tags: python, for-loop, neural-network, nan

I'm trying to train a neural network for a HW (can't use classes). I have pretty much everything figured out, but when it comes to updating the weights, I fixed the shape error I had, but the resulting weights are [nan nan nan, nan nan...], which shouldn't happen. I'm not asking anyone to do my HW for me, I'm just not sure where in the code I need to fix.

```
# Creating the activation function: Sigmoid function ==> h(x) = 1/1+e^(-x)
def sig(x):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
# Derivative of act. function:
def deriv(x):
    return x*(1-x)
# Establishing inputs and outputs
x = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1]])
y = np.array([[1], [0], [0], [1], [1]])
alpha = 0.05
#print(x.shape)
np.random.seed(1)
# Establishing weights randomly with a mean of 0 for a weight matrix
w = np.random.uniform(low=-0.4, high=0.4, size=(3,1))
print('Random weight:',w)

# Going to iterate 1000 times
for _ in range(1000):
    # Feed Forward:
    # Input  
    z = np.dot(x, w)
    h = sig(z)
    # Output 
    yhat = sig(z)

    # Backpropagation:
    # Calculating the errors:
    J = ((1/2)*(np.power((yhat - y), 2)))
    deltay = yhat - y
    grad = deriv(z)
    dz = deltay*grad
    const = np.dot(dz, w.T)
    dJdw = np.dot(x.T, const*deriv(z)) 
    #print(dJdw.shape)
    #print(w.shape)
    # Update the weights (shape is messing this and 3 up for some reason....)
    w = w - alpha*dJdw

print('Weights after training: ',w)
print('Outputs after training: ',y_hat)
print('Error obtained: ',delta_y)
```

Comment: Debug it step by step to see where the NaNs are coming from.

Comment: I changed things around with the gradients now done in a def function, but now the values just don't make sense, i.e. the weights after training don't change which is clealy incorrect.